# Concatenate (append) one input field value to another field in angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

Trying to auto-populate first input field value into second input field value, However if the second input field as existing values then i would like to append / concatenate the first input field value to second.

logic:

```
if ( second ){
second = first + second;
}else{
second = first;
}
```

html:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='owner' required class="form-control">
<input type='text' ng-model='member' required class="form-control">
```

code:

```
app.controller("Controller", ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.owner;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( $scope.member ){
      $scope.member = $scope.owner + ',' + $scope.member;
    }else{
      $scope.member = newValue;
    }
}, true);

}]);
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AFRpTL9N55EFtHViAa76?p=preview)

Update (**problem**):

When i type `Jake` in Owner Field, it loops through the letters and print's as `Jake,Jak,Ja,J`in member field. If i have pre-existing value `Adam` in member field, upon entering `Tom` in owner filed it will create `Tom,To,T,Adam` in member field. Please check the plunker for demo.

Comment: ... and is that code not working? how is it not working? are you getting errors? what are the expected inputs/outputs?

Comment: It is working. What's the matter?

Comment: Don't do this.  Code-wise it will work fine.  UI-wise, it's completely unsalvageable.  (What happens if I fill in field 2, then notice a typo in field 1, and go back to correct it?)  Concatenate the values into a third, not-directly-user-modifiable space on screen, if at all.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Any response would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mad-D consider changing your approach as it is prone to a circular dependency based on the way ng-model works.

You already have access to both values and you can display it in other ways. Plus your controller looks cleaner and acts as a true view model (vm):

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxz00zYeBmVaMW1l3PRn?p=preview)**

```
app.controller("Controller",  function(){

  var myCtrl = this;

  myCtrl.owner = "";
  myCtrl.member = "";

});
```

Comment: thanks for your input. But the user needs `owner` value auto-populated inside `member` input field.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C961xfkUhWN3HeN34v7V?p=preview)
. And also given below. Check whether it's correct one for you.

```js
var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);

app.controller("Controller", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.permaMember = $scope.member?$scope.member:'';
  $scope.editSecond = function(member){
      $scope.permaMember = member?member:'';
  }
  $scope.editFirst = function(owner){
    if(owner){
      $scope.member = $scope.permaMember + owner
    }
    else{
      $scope.member = $scope.permaMember
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="form-example1">
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <form name="testform">
  <div class='form-group'>
   <label>Owner</label>
  <input type='text' ng-model='owner' required class="form-control" ng-change="editFirst(owner)">
 </div>


 <div class='form-group'>
    <label>Member</label>
     <input type='text' ng-model='member' required class="form-control" ng-change="editSecond(member)">
 </div>
 <button ng-disabled="testform.$invalid" ng-click ="submit()">SAVE</button>
</form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just have a 3rd read only text box or label that displays $scope.owner, $scope.member?

Comment: I think this should be a comment